# Launch editor from a shell script with text

Tags: shell-script, editors

I know it is possible to launch the default editor from a shell script. For example, assuming the `$EDITOR` environment variable is set:

```
$EDITOR ~/newfile.txt
```

Is it possible to open a new file with pre-populated text?
One way I can think of is to create the file before opening it:

```
echo "Header" > ~/newfile.txt
$EDITOR ~/newfile.txt
```

But it would be slightly nicer if the file which the text editor opens is pre-populated, but also capable of being thrown away. Is this possible?

Comment: The way you suggested is the way it should be done. I.e., put some prepopulated content in a file, in some way, shape or form then open it with `$EDITOR filename` command. Do you need something different ? If you are inquiring if the OS or the editor of your choice supports such an arrangement, without requiring creating the file somehow, it all depends the editor of your choice and capabilities of that editor. It is not something that OS could provide for you.

Comment: I just want to put the editor in the state it would be in if you typed a few lines after opening it. If at that point you quit the editor,  It should throw the file away. That's the behaviour of every editor I have used, so I thought this might be possible somehow.

Comment: If it's doable, it's not doable in a generic way such that you can use $EDITOR.

Comment: I had imagined something like what git does when you commit, though I guess that uses some trickery with git hooks below the hood to move the file from `<repo>/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`  to a useful location after you save it.

Comment: The behavior of ANY editor, depends on the editor's capabilities. And in most part, every editor, who opens a document upon invocation, do not throw the document away. If you made a change it asks you if you want to save it. If you haven't made any change, no-harm, no-fault it keeps the file as it for the next invocation. Your expectancies are not based on an EDITOR's capability, it is the way you configure it to act the way you want it to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pre-populate content in the editor, write this initial content to the file, just like you thought.

There is no way to “put the editor in the state it would be in if you typed a few lines after opening it” that works across diverse editors. In many editors, this means that the file will be unsaved, but there's no uniform way to achieve that state, and there are editors that don't have this concept at all (e.g. [Scratch](https://launchpad.net/scratch)).

You can however detect whether the file was saved at all from the editor. Abandon the operation if the file wasn't saved. To detect whether the file was saved, check its modification time before and after.

```
file=$(mktemp)
cat <<EOF >"$file"
Hello
world
EOF
old_metadata=$(ls -li "$file")
"${VISUAL:-"${EDITOR:-vi}"}" "$file"
new_metadata=$(ls -li "$file")
if [ "$new_metadata" = "$old_metadata" ]; then
  … # unchanged file, abandon operation
else
  … # modified file, carry on
fi
```

Beware that if the file was modified but the size and inode didn't change and the modification took less than 1 second, this script will think that the file hasn't been modified. This won't happen if a human is editing, but it could easily happen if `$EDITOR` is a script that submits a modified file automatically. It's difficult to do better in a portable way. With GNU coreutils, passing the `--full-time` option to `ls` solves this problem if the filesystem supports subsecond timestamps with sufficient precision.

Alternatively, check whether the file has been modified. The portable way of doing this is to keep a copy of the initial content and call `cmp`. If commands like `sha256sum` or `sha` are available, you can use these and compare the hashes before and after. You may still want to consider the file to have been edited if its timestamp has changed — maybe the user did want to submit the default input.

This technique is what several version control systems use when they launch an editor to edit a commit message. If the user doesn't save the file, the commit is aborted.

If you also want to place the cursor at the end of the input, there's no universal way to do that. With many editors, you can write

```
"$EDITOR" +"$line" "$file"
```

and the editor will open with the cursor on the specified line. This is supported by many editors including vi (all variants), emacs, joe and gedit, but not by kwrite.

Comment: I've often wondered how version control systems handle this. Very nice to know!